# Android translucent theme

Tags: android, translucency

I have on one side, an android application.
On the other side a video stream.

The two of them are combined together using an image mixer that puts the android application over the video stream.

Something similar to tv banner:
[image: tv banner]

I am trying to make the android application translucent in order to "see through" to the image under it.

My problem is that when I set the android application theme to `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` , I then see the wallpaper and the launcher of Android OS.

This image found online shows the result:
[image: Result of translucent theme]

I there a way to get rid of the wallpaper and the launcher behind the application to not have anything behind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing the launcher, it doesn't sound like your app is on top of the video, your app is around the video.  Step 1 for this would be to make the video fullscreen, then put the app on top of it.  Then the transparency code will work.

Comment: The video is not being rendered by android, it is a completely separate OS. The 2 are then being merged on top of each other using a separate hardware.

Comment: Then getting rid of the underlieing wallpaper/launcher won't help you.  Even if you got rid of them and had black or white underneath it, making the app transparent would just dim/brighten the app.  You need your merger to do alpha blending and place the android content on top of the video.

Comment: I was hoping to get rid of the stuff behind to get an alpha transparent layer that would go on top...
I guess I need to capture the android screen with alpha and send it to the blender instead of sending the whole android screen.

Comment: Its not going to work that way.  To do alpha blending, you need to know what's on both layers.  What you want is a fully opaque app so that you can't see the stuff behind it and the alpha blender on your merger will never know it exists.  You can't just set it as transparent like in a png, because that kind of transparency isn't an actual color-  its an instruction to the drawer on what to do.

Comment: In addition, if you're not displaying on the android device why are you even drawing to the screen?  If you're streaming it elsewhere drawing to an off screen canvas would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean... I need to investigate in Chroma Key to have the blender recreate the transparency.
I am drawing something on the android app mostly text that I want to put on top of the video.